# Kotlin/JS: How to use a Dukat external interface that has functions in it

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, lottie, kotlin-js

I'm trying to use Lottie along with Kotlin/JS.

I've been able to create a Lottie external declarations file with Dukat, which gave me an external interface called `AnimationConfig` (represents the parameters of the animation that will be played by `LottiePlayer`), an external interface called `LottiePlayer` (represents all the animation player functions), as well as a variable called `Lottie` (of type `LottiePlayer`):

```
@file:JsModule("lottie-web")
@file:JsNonModule
@file:Suppress("INTERFACE_WITH_SUPERCLASS", "OVERRIDING_FINAL_MEMBER", "RETURN_TYPE_MISMATCH_ON_OVERRIDE", "CONFLICTING_OVERLOADS")

external interface AnimationConfig {
    var container: Element
    var renderer: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var loop: dynamic /* Boolean? | Number? */
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var autoplay: Boolean?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var initialSegment: dynamic /* JsTuple<Number, Number> */
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var name: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var assetsPath: String?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    var rendererSettings: Any?
        get() = definedExternally
        set(value) = definedExternally
    val audioFactory: ((assetPath: String) -> `T$1`)?
}

external interface LottiePlayer {
    fun play(name: String = definedExternally)
    fun pause(name: String = definedExternally)
    fun stop(name: String = definedExternally)
    fun setSpeed(speed: Number, name: String = definedExternally)
    fun setDirection(direction: Number /* 1 */, name: String = definedExternally)
    fun setDirection(direction: Number /* 1 */)
    fun setDirection(direction: String /* "-1" */, name: String = definedExternally)
    fun setDirection(direction: String /* "-1" */)
    fun searchAnimations(animationData: Any = definedExternally, standalone: Boolean = definedExternally, renderer: String = definedExternally)
    fun loadAnimation(params: AnimationConfig /* AnimationConfig<T> & `T$5` | AnimationConfig<T> & `T$6` */): AnimationItem
    fun destroy(name: String = definedExternally)
    fun registerAnimation(element: Element, animationData: Any = definedExternally)
    fun setQuality(quality: String)
    fun setQuality(quality: Number)
    fun setLocationHref(href: String)
    fun setIDPrefix(prefix: String)
    fun updateDocumentData(path: Array<Any /* String | Number */>, documentData: TextDocumentData, index: Number)
}

@JsName("default")
external var Lottie: LottiePlayer
```

Then in the Kotlin/JS side, I'm trying to use these externals to play an animation inside a `Div` generated with Kotlin compose for web. Here is my `main()` function:

```
fun main() {
    renderComposable(rootElementId = "root") {

        Div( attrs = {
            id("svgContainer")
        }) {

            Text("Hola mundo!")

            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            DomSideEffect {

                val svgContainer = it

                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST_TO_EXTERNAL_INTERFACE")
                val animationConfig = js("{}") as AnimationConfig
                animationConfig.container = svgContainer
                animationConfig.loop = false
                animationConfig.autoplay = true
                animationConfig.assetsPath = "https://labs.nearpod.com/bodymovin/demo/markus/halloween/markus.json"

                Lottie.loadAnimation(animationConfig)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that the application throws a runtime error indicating that the variable `Lottie` is undefined:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadAnimation')

I haven't found a way to use the available variable `Lottie` in order to get an instance of it and use it.

How should I use either the variable `Lottie` or the external interface `LottiePlayer`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Dukat is incredibly experimental, and essentially never generates the correct bindings, if it works at all. It's best used as an initial step to generate a starting point, and then manually implementing the correct bindings by manually inspecting and understanding the actual JavaScript and TypeScript.

##### Inspecting the TypeScript types

Looking at the `index.d.ts` for `lottie-web` I can see [the definition for `LottiePlayer`](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/blob/6faae912910b2d7be6c5422ef4621f3933c19d60/index.d.ts#L130-L144).

The relevant part is the `loadAnimation()` function.

```js
export type LottiePlayer = {
    // ...
    loadAnimation<T extends RendererType = 'svg'>(params: AnimationConfigWithPath<T> | AnimationConfigWithData<T>): AnimationItem;
    // ...
}
```

The function accepts a union type with two different types,

- `AnimationConfigWithPath<T>`
- `AnimationConfigWithData<T>`

These both extend a base type, `AnimationConfig<T>`.

##### Comparing with the generated code

However Dukat has generated a function that only accepts `AnimationConfig`

```kotlin
external interface LottiePlayer {
    // ...
    fun loadAnimation(params: AnimationConfig /* AnimationConfig<T> & `T$5` | AnimationConfig<T> & `T$6` */): AnimationItem
    // ...
}
```

(Dukat has also generated a comment (`` /* AnimationConfig<T> & `T$5` | AnimationConfig<T> & `T$6` */ ``) indicating that it knows that the argument is a union type.)

##### Bindings for generic types, `<T extends RendererType>`

The generated `AnimationConfig` does not have a type parameter, which might usually be a problem. It's not surprising that Dukat failed because the parameter is bounded by a string union, which isn't something that's easily mappable to Kotlin.

```js
export type RendererType = 'svg' | 'canvas' | 'html';

export type AnimationConfig<T extends RendererType = 'svg'> = {
    // ...
}
```

However it is bounded to be a constant string, `'svg'`, so the Kotlin binding doesn't need to be aware of it - any instance of `T` will just return a string. Fortunately the same is true of the subtypes, `AnimationConfigWithPath` and `AnimationConfigWithData`.

##### Fixing the Kotlin bindings

Kotlin doesn't have union types, which can be an issue when trying to [bind functions that return unions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72109734/4161471). It's not a problem with functions arguments though, because that's the same as function overloading, which Kotlin already has.

```kotlin
external interface LottiePlayer {
    // fun loadAnimation(params: AnimationConfig /* AnimationConfig<T> & `T$5` | AnimationConfig<T> & `T$6` */): AnimationItem
    fun loadAnimation(params: AnimationConfigWithPath): AnimationItem
    fun loadAnimation(params: AnimationConfigWithData): AnimationItem
}
```

And then you have to define externals for `AnimationConfigWithPath` and `AnimationConfigWithData`.

```kotlin
external interface AnimationConfigWithPath : AnimationConfig {
    var animationData: dynamic
}

external interface AnimationConfigWithData : AnimationConfig {
    var animationData: dynamic
}
```

I haven't tested this code - so if there are corrections please let me know.