# How can I add my own version of dukat in intellij idea

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I am trying to generate external Declaration for a NPM package but it is giving errors
But when I tried the same with dukat@next version it worked
Tell me either how can I include my generated declarations to my kotlinJs project or how can I update to dukat@next in IDE to automatically generate declarations and use it

I am expecting for dukat to generate my Declarations and i can work with my npm module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kotlin/JS Gradle plugin configures the version of Dukat via an extension on the *root* Gradle project (even if the root project does not have the Kotlin/JS plugin applied).

The latest version of Dukat can be found on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dukat?activeTab=versions). Right now, the latest version is `0.5.8-rc.4-dev.20221020`

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.nodejs.NodeJsRootExtension
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.nodejs.NodeJsRootPlugin

rootProject.plugins.withType<NodeJsRootPlugin> {
  configure<NodeJsRootExtension> {
    versions.apply {
      dukat.version = "0.5.8-rc.4-dev.20221020"
    }
  }
}
```

There are actually a lot of versions that can be configured. The full list (for Kotlin v1.8.0) can be viewed in [NpmVersions.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.8.0/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/common/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/NpmVersions.kt)

I wouldn't rely on Dukat too much though. It's still highly experimental, and is updated rarely. Further development has been [postponed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42290) a number of times. It rarely generates correct code, but it can be used as a good starting point ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726082/4161471)).